# how to choose what key to Update?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to choose a field to Update from my sqlite3 db using postman by utilizing request.data. However, I receive this error "OperationalError at /
near "?": syntax error". I tried this code

```
def put(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('/Users/lambda_school_loaner_182/Documents/job-search-be/jobsearchbe/db.sqlite3')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        req = request.data
        for key in req:
            if key == id:
                pass
            else:
                print(key)  
                cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?;",(key,req[key],req['id']) )
        connection.commit()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?", (request.data['id'],))
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        data = []
        # if request.data['id']
        for row in results:
            object1 = {}
            col_name_list = [tuple[0] for tuple in cursor.description]
            for x in range(0,len(col_name_list) ):
                object1[col_name_list[x]] = row[x]
            data.append(object1)
        cursor.close()

        # serializer =PostSerializer(data = request.data )
        # if serializer.is_valid():
        #   serializer.save()
        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `?` for identifiers (the database structures, like table and column names). You will need to use string interpolation to put in the column name.

`f"UPDATE users SET {key} = ? WHERE id = ?"`

`?` are basically for values (user-supplied data).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see https://xkcd.com/327/ for humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put ? as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method. (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as %s or :1.)